# Can I join the results from a like where clause, to another table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I would like to do a search on one table "Customers" using LIKE with a wild card and with these results JOIN on another "RECEIPTS" not sure how to achieve this, I am using an access database

ie

```
SELECT customercode, firstname, lastname FROM customers WHERE customercode LIKE *searchterm AS RESULTS 
INNER JOIN receipts ON customers.customercode = receipts.customercode
```

I am not sure how to structure this query, joining the 2 before the WHERE seem very sluggish as there are many RECEIPTS matching CUSTOMERS. So I would like to CULL the set to just the matching customer first then join this to RECEIPTS on matching customer code.

Any help appreciated.

```
SELECT customercode, firstname, lastname FROM customers WHERE customercode LIKE *searchterm AS RESULTS 
INNER JOIN receipts ON customers.customercode = receipts.customercode
```

I am currently using

```
SELECT Docketnumber, date, total, tblcustomer.customercode, firstname, lastname, businessname FROM tblreceipts INNER JOIN tblcustomer on tblreceipts.customercode = tblcustomer.customercode WHERE firstname like 'c%'
```

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the customers and then join to receipts like this:

```
SELECT c.customercode, c.firstname, c.lastname 
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM customers 
  WHERE customercode LIKE '*searchterm'
) AS c INNER JOIN receipts AS r 
ON c.customercode = r.customercode
```

Comment: Thats more like it - I wasnt sure how to filter my customer list first then join to the receipts table, Ill give this a go and report back

Comment: Much faster, I thought it was a better approach thanks for your assistance

Answer (score 0):

You could use a join for relate  the tables and filter the result from customers  using your where condition

```
    SELECT c.customercode
        , c.firstname
        , c.lastname 
    FROM customers c
    INNER JOIN receipts r ON c.customercode = r.customercode
    WHERE c.customercode LIKE '%your_value%'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want information from the `customers` table, I would recommend `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT c.customercode, c.firstname, c.lastname
FROM customers as c
WHERE c.customercode LIKE "*searchterm" AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM receipts as r
              WHERE c.customercode = r.customercode
             );
```

Very importantly:  This does not return multiple rows if a customer has multiple receipts.  You would use a join if you wanted columns from the `receipts` table, but that is not the case with your question.